# working on file type .results using python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in terms of coding in python. I have some hundreds of files which are of type .results(RESULTS file) when looked into their properties. These files are supposedly tab delimited text files but I do not know why there are saved as .results type. I can open the file in a text editor or in excel. But I want to write a python code to iterate through all these files and pickup one single column from each of these and create a matrix in other file.

So, basically I have written a simple python code to just open one such file, read all the lines and write them into a text file. But the code throws an error as per written in the code.

```
def FileCheck(fIn,fOut):

    try:
        fIn = open(fIn,"U")
    except IOError:
        print "Error: File does not appear to exist. Check the file and the directory path."
        return 0
    fOut = open(fOut,"w")
    for line in fIn:
        fOut.write(line)
    fIn.close()
    fOut.close()
    return fOut

out=FileCheck("pateint 1.results","duh2.txt")
```

Result:
Error: File does not appear to exist. Check the file and the directory path.

I guess this is because the file is not being recognized as a valid file format. It would be great if anyone of you could let me know who to work with such kind of files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The open() function in Python can open files in any format. Please check that you don't have any typos in your path (is the file really called `pateint` and not `patient`?)

Comment: you may want to look into the standard module csv, which can take a delimiter argument. Also, open() can be used as a guard so you do not need to explicitly call .close()

Comment: Yeah that was a typo while saving a file so I followed the same in my code as well.